# Unable to debug a REST application deployed on WebLogic 12.2.1 (admin server) via Netbeans debug

Tags: debugging, java-8, cdi, netbeans-8, weblogic12c

***PROBLEM:  I've been unable to debug a CDI/REST app on WebLogic 12.2.1 (admin server) via Netbeans debug facility.  Not sure what the problem is.***

*I noticed the following, but, not certain whether these things are related to the issue...*

**SERVER LOG**

```
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Cannot create new registration for component type class org.glassfish.json.jaxrs.JsonStructureBodyReader: Existing previous registration found for the type.
WARNING: Cannot create new registration for component type class org.glassfish.json.jaxrs.JsonStructureBodyWriter: Existing previous registration found for the type.
```

**WebLogic console/Deployments**

```
under "Deployments", the application "unknown" under the "Type" column
```

**Browser displays to following when app is "started"...**

```
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:323) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305) at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:471) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137) at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350) at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32) at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649) at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326) at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197) at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203) at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259) at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691) at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651) at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348) at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333) at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54) at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

*Please note, that I am able to deploy the application, manually, via the WebLogic console*

Let me know what other relevant data I can provide to help.

Thanks for any ideas/direction on how I might successfully use the Netbeans 8.2 debugger on this application (deployed to WebLogic version 12.2.1.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using this technique I'd used to shorten the REST URL path (eliminates the need for the '/resources' part) ...i.e.,

**MyApplication.java**

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application {

}
```

...causes the issue I described, above.

When I eliminated the class the debugger began to work (i.e., application worked [deployed to Weblogic server] as it should).